# How to make the image expand and fit the screen on scroll?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a photographic background and a SVG graphics to use as mask. I used an  image as a background-image and the svg mask as a mask-image on the same element, and get something like this:

My Question is on scroll I want to expand this image and make it fit to the screen on mouse scroll.

Do i need any other third-party plugins for this to achieve ?

I have used JavaScript but not getting the desire result.

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
        const el = document.querySelector('.el');
        const scrollPercent = window.scrollY / (document.documentElement.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight);
        const newSize = (100 + scrollPercent * 100) + 'vw';
        el.style.width = newSize;
        el.style.height = newSize;
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #8f7a66;
}

.el {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 1rem;

  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1528287942171-fbe365d1d9ac?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&w=1200&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ);
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

  mask-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/sun.svg);
  mask-size: 50vmin;
  mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  mask-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="el"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

You've gotten it correctly in the linked [codepen](https://codepen.io/jhunumandal/pen/WNYedXN)

Few corrections:

- `mask-*` properties require vendor prefix
- Use css variables.
- Simply remove the upper limit you've set (100) to something else.

This value is the total % required to fit the largest dimension in the inner part of the svg.

For example, say if the inner part is 50% of the size of svg, you would set the limit to 200%

```js
const el = document.querySelector('.el');
let maskSize = 100;
el.style.setProperty("--mask-size", `${maskSize}%`);
const limit = 200;



window.addEventListener('wheel', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  const scrollAmount = event.deltaY;
  maskSize += scrollAmount * -0.1;

  maskSize = maskSize < 0 ? 0 : maskSize > limit ? limit : maskSize;



  el.style.setProperty("--mask-size", `${maskSize}%`);
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #8f7a66;
}

.el {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1528287942171-fbe365d1d9ac?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&w=1200&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ);
  -webkit-mask-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/sun.svg);
  -webkit-mask-size: var(--mask-size);
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask-position: center;
  mask-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/sun.svg);
  mask-size: var(--mask-size);
  mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  mask-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="el"></div>
```

Comment: Not Like this. The SVG  Will Expand and Fit to the Screen So that Only the  background-image will visible. The Sun will go transparent. And again on scroll up the Sun will be visible with the Mask. See this https://www.accenture.com/in-en (in-en site only).

Comment: You did not add that in your question

Comment: My Bad, please see this Instead of the Circle I need the SVG https://codepen.io/Sashikanta-Nayak/pen/bGmjvMJ

Comment: @AnitaMandal haven't tried it yet, but instead of `background-size`, you can change `mask-size`. Note that `mask-size` requires vendor prefixes. I'll edit the question when I get some time. You may have to change the `mask-position` if you want to keep the mask in the centre of the screen

Comment: Please see this the codepen is working now but I want to expand the Star to fit the screen so that the star will not display, only background content will display. (if you see the Accenture India website, I need something like that). https://codepen.io/jhunumandal/pen/WNYedXN

Please find some time and work on this, Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Your codepen does not work in chrome. I checked on firefox, and the problem seems to very simple.

Comment: I saw you fixed the issues and updated your answer. Thank you Very much for this. Can we fixed the Sun,svg to a initial size like 150px to height and width so from there it will start expanding ? Also can we hide on make transparent the image when its fit to the viewport screen.  Like  mask-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 10%, black);

Comment: @AnitaMandal yeah, you can set a minimum value, just like the maximum. Not sure what you mean by the transparent part, I don't think you can change the opacity of of mask directly. but you can try out the `mask-mode` and `mask-composite` property. or maybe change the opacity of the svg filter itself (by changing the `mask-image` itself)